# Bound DataGrid not updating but TextBoxes bound to same object do

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

On a WPF form I have a `DataGrid` and several `TextBox`elements which are bound using two-way binding to different properties contained in a single object.  All data displays just fine and the data in the `TextBox` elements will allow user editing and update without a problem.  When I edit a value in the `DataGrid` however I get a "Two-way binding requires Path or XPath" exception when leaving the edited cell. Any idea why?

The data object is defined as:

```
public class Options : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> ignoreList;
    private decimal minimumPrice;
    private decimal maximumPrice;
    private int maximumDimension;
    private int targetMargin;

    public Options()
    {
        this.IgnoreList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<string> IgnoreList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ignoreList;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ignoreList = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IgnoreList");
        }
    }

    public decimal MinimumPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.minimumPrice;
        }
        set
        {
            this.minimumPrice = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("MinimumPrice");
        }
    }

    public decimal MaximumPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.maximumPrice;
        }
        set
        {
            this.maximumPrice = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("MaximumPrice");
        }
    }

    public int MaximumDimension
    {
        get
        {
            return this.maximumDimension;
        }
        set
        {
            this.maximumDimension = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("MaximumDimension");
        }
    }

    public int TargetMargin
    {
        get
        {
            return this.targetMargin;
        }
        set
        {
            this.targetMargin = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("TargetMargin");
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML is:

```
<Grid Name="optionsGrid">
    <TextBox x:Name="minimumPrice" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="251,11,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MinimumPrice}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="maximumPrice" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="251,61,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MaximumPrice}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="maximumDimension" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="251,112,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MaximumDimension}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="targetMargin" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="251,161,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding TargetMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="74"/>
    <Button x:Name="cancelButton" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="170,231,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Click="cancelButton_Click" Height="20"/>
    <Button x:Name="okButton" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,231,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Height="20" Click="okButton_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="ignoreGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Margin="10,31,0,0" IsReadOnly="False" ItemsSource="{Binding IgnoreList, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="146">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ignoreList" Binding="{Binding Path=.}" Width="144"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The relevant part of the code behind is:

```
public OptionsDialog(OptionsController options)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Options options = new Options();
    options.MaximumDimension = 77;
    options.MinimumPrice = 0.50m;
    options.MaximumPrice = 99.99m;
    options.TargetMargin = 49;
    options.IgnoreList.Add("aaa");
    options.IgnoreList.Add("bbb");

    this.optionsGrid.DataContext = options;
}
```

**Update 1**

Having changed the DataGridTextColumn definition as per HamletHakobyan's suggestion to:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="ignoreList" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="144"/>
```

the error has stopped.  However now when an edited cell is left the cell simply reverts back to its original value.  As an experiment I generated another TextBlock and bound IgnoreList[0] to this.  It worked perfectly.  This suggests to me that the problem is with the data grid definition rather than with the source data definition or the binding.  I can't seem to move forward from this however.

**Update 2**

Something else I've noticed that might be relevant is that the datagrid doesn't show a blank row at the bottom even though CanUserAddRows="True".  It's as though the grid is locked in some way. Yet I *can* delete rows successfully by clicking on a row and hitting the Delete key and I *can* add rows to IgnoreList through code.  I've also pointed the debugger at the setter for IgnoreList in the Options class.  This *doesn't* fire when I change the value of a cell.  No idea why.

Comment: Error message have clearly mentioned the problem. Use `Binding="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}`.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I'd understood that Path=. was necessary where I'm declaring ItemsSource="{Binding IgnoreList, Mode=TwoWay}" for the DataGrid. (Can't find the relevant article now - sorry)!  Certainly it was adding this that finally got my DataGrid displaying data correctly, though not updating.  Before this I was getting the _length_ of the items in the collection displayed rather than the data strings themselves.  If the syntax is wrong any suggestions as to how it should be corrected?

Comment: Why do you write this? I suggested the solution, have you tried?

Comment: @ifinlay Avoid forcing tags into question topic, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging "The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."

Comment: @Tseng, so? Why do your write it for me?

Comment: Sorry, looked at wrong name. Meant to be for ifinlay.

Comment: Tagging point noted.  There was no intentional force!

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Apologies I'd slightly misread your response.  I've now tried the syntax you suggest with partial success.  The error has gone away but when I leave the edited cell it simply reverts back to its original value.